# Reading contents shared on Windows machine from Unix Box with a Java Program

Tags: java

I have shared contents on windows machine say \someip\somedirectory and now I want to write a program in Java that runs on Unix Box and reads contents of the shared folder.

```
File file=new File(directoryPath);
if(file.isDirectory()) returns false.
```

Therefore I am failing on the first step itself. Please suggest how can I do that.

Comment: What exactly is your question and where do you have problems?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `return` instead of `returns`:

```
File file=new File(directoryPath);
if(file.isDirectory()) return false;
```